# factor with 6 levels out of a continuous variable

Tags: r, factors

I have a continuous variable of frequency that ranges from 0 to 6.115053.
I need to split that in 6 levels, my analysis will be more readable this way.

I have tried:

```
frequency.new <-  hist(all$frequency, 6, plot = FALSE)
all$frequency <- as.factor(frequency.new)
```

but i get an error which i don't understand:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 
  'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Anybody can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Katerina

Answer (score 7):

You should look at the `cut()` function in base R. You should also note the last line of my Answer (in bold) before venturing further.

```
> set.seed(42)
> cut(runif(50), 6)
 [1] (0.825,0.99]    (0.825,0.99]    (0.167,0.332]   (0.825,0.99]   
 [5] (0.496,0.661]   (0.496,0.661]   (0.661,0.825]   (0.00296,0.167]
 [9] (0.496,0.661]   (0.661,0.825]   (0.332,0.496]   (0.661,0.825]  
[13] (0.825,0.99]    (0.167,0.332]   (0.332,0.496]   (0.825,0.99]   
[17] (0.825,0.99]    (0.00296,0.167] (0.332,0.496]   (0.496,0.661]  
[21] (0.825,0.99]    (0.00296,0.167] (0.825,0.99]    (0.825,0.99]   
[25] (0.00296,0.167] (0.496,0.661]   (0.332,0.496]   (0.825,0.99]   
[29] (0.332,0.496]   (0.825,0.99]    (0.661,0.825]   (0.661,0.825]  
[33] (0.332,0.496]   (0.661,0.825]   (0.00296,0.167] (0.825,0.99]   
[37] (0.00296,0.167] (0.167,0.332]   (0.825,0.99]    (0.496,0.661]  
[41] (0.332,0.496]   (0.332,0.496]   (0.00296,0.167] (0.825,0.99]   
[45] (0.332,0.496]   (0.825,0.99]    (0.825,0.99]    (0.496,0.661]  
[49] (0.825,0.99]    (0.496,0.661]  
6 Levels: (0.00296,0.167] (0.167,0.332] (0.332,0.496] ... (0.825,0.99]
```

`cut()` returns a factor that indexes which of the, in this case, 6 groups that observed data fall. This is just a simple splitting of the range of the data into 6 groups of equal interval. Read `?cut` for details on what to do at the extremes of the intervals.

The reason your code fails is because the object returned by `hist()` is a list containing far more than your data broken in to groups:

```
> foo <- hist(runif(50), breaks = 6, plot = FALSE)
> str(foo)
List of 7
 $ breaks     : num [1:6] 0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1
 $ counts     : int [1:5] 12 13 7 13 5
 $ intensities: num [1:5] 1.2 1.3 0.7 1.3 0.5
 $ density    : num [1:5] 1.2 1.3 0.7 1.3 0.5
 $ mids       : num [1:5] 0.1 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.9
 $ xname      : chr "runif(50)"
 $ equidist   : logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

so you can;t just convert this to a factor - R doesn't know how to do that. Notice also, that `hist()` doesn't return the data broken down into the 6 groups - it provides other information useful for building a histogram. Also note that it will produce *pretty* breaks, unlike `cut()`. If you want these pretty breaks, then we can reproduce what `hist()` does by:

```
> set.seed(42)
> x <- runif(50)
> brks <- pretty(range(x), n = 6, min.n = 1)
> cut(x, breaks = brks)
 [1] (0.8,1]   (0.8,1]   (0.2,0.4] (0.8,1]   (0.6,0.8] (0.4,0.6] (0.6,0.8]
 [8] (0,0.2]   (0.6,0.8] (0.6,0.8] (0.4,0.6] (0.6,0.8] (0.8,1]   (0.2,0.4]
[15] (0.4,0.6] (0.8,1]   (0.8,1]   (0,0.2]   (0.4,0.6] (0.4,0.6] (0.8,1]  
[22] (0,0.2]   (0.8,1]   (0.8,1]   (0,0.2]   (0.4,0.6] (0.2,0.4] (0.8,1]  
[29] (0.4,0.6] (0.8,1]   (0.6,0.8] (0.8,1]   (0.2,0.4] (0.6,0.8] (0,0.2]  
[36] (0.8,1]   (0,0.2]   (0.2,0.4] (0.8,1]   (0.6,0.8] (0.2,0.4] (0.4,0.6]
[43] (0,0.2]   (0.8,1]   (0.4,0.6] (0.8,1]   (0.8,1]   (0.6,0.8] (0.8,1]  
[50] (0.6,0.8]
Levels: (0,0.2] (0.2,0.4] (0.4,0.6] (0.6,0.8] (0.8,1]
```

**But you should be asking yourself why you want to discretise your data so and whether this makes sense?**

Comment: Thanks @Aaron - I was in two minds as to even suggest an Answer. I think I'm going to emphasise the last comment! :-)

Comment: Well, this could be a reasonable thing to do, especially as part of an explanation of a more sophisticated analysis, but as it's hard to tell what the OP has in mind, I think it's good you included the advice about whether this makes sense.